# beforeinstallprompt not firing in iOS

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, beforeinstallprompt

1. Website Url: [redacted]
2. Prompt works in Samsung Internet, Windows Desktop Chrome, Android Chrome
3. Prompt does NOT work in Safari or Chrome for iOS
4. Lighthouse tests pass (ignore the start_url error, whether or not I fix that has no effect. I've tried)
5. PWA is installable on Android, iOS, and Windows
6. Offline mode works as expected in the PWA
7. When I run the lighthouse test, I get console error (even though image DOES exist): Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: [redacted]/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
8. Manifest is valid and no syntax errors
9. The actual app is an Angular 9 app running at /app
10. "Continue In Browser" button should disappear and be replaced with "Install The App" button when beforeinstallprompt fires

The PWA works on iOS, so why doesn't the prompt work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BeforeInstallPromptEvent API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_beforeinstallpromptevent) is supported by Chrome and Edge. Safari (Webkit) does not support it and on iOS [all browsers are Webkit under the hood](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/01/new-chrome-for-ios-is-finally-as-fast-and-stable-as-safari/).