# Pwa beforeInstallPrompt not firing in mobile browser but working in normal desktop browser

Tags: html, css, reactjs, workbox

I am using workbox with create react app.
here is the code

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", event => {
    window.deferredPrompt = event;

  });
```

Comment: Not all mobile browsers support this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62760846/8810271) might help.